# Why does my server not seem to find the texture?

Tags: server, lua, client, textures, garrys-mod

so we are about to improve our garrysmod server...
We want to add weaponicons to the weapon selection hud (scrolling)

So I made an addon: https://steamcommunity.com/sharedfiles/filedetails/?id=1988793385
(Currently has only one material in it)
Feel free to extract it :)

And in my darkrpmodifications addon i have inside of a module in a shared file:

```
weapon("arrest_stick").WepSelectIcon = surface.GetTextureID("hud/wepicons/icon_arrest")
```

Problem is that ingame only the pink / black "not found" texture (dunno what to call it) appears as icon... And in my local gmod folder under the downloaded materials it also doesn't show the folder / icons provided in this addon...

Why is that please help me :(

Thank you in advance,
TheSaltyOne (Aaron).

EDIT: Here is my .vmt File:

```
"UnlitGeneric"
{
    "$basetexture" "hud/wepicons/icon_arrest"
    "$translucent" 1
    "$vertexalpha" 1
    "$vertexcolor" 1
}
```

EDIT2:
After trying some stuff I now get the server to download it... (It shows in the cache/srcds)
But even if I download it as  client... 1. It doesnt show in my local addons folder and the texture is still not working :(

SOLUTION: FIXED IT!! I now have added the materials inside the addon and the server and provided a lua/autorun/sh_init.lua that does `resource.AddFile` to all the materials ^^

Comment: Steam registration is required to download your script :-(

Comment: Oh that might actually also be the reason for it not working as i run the server as anonymous...
How do I change it? :)

Answer (score 0):

FIXED IT!! I now have added the materials inside the addon and the server and provided a lua/autorun/sh_init.lua that does resource.AddFile to all the materials ^^